# Is there any solution to load GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin file on anaconda python?

Tags: python, anaconda

When I am loading the file in anaconda2  then 2 to 3 hrs loaded start message occurs

[image]

And then the system hangs and could not perform any action help me please see the screenshot below:

Comment: yeah.. the file is too big to be loaded by your local machine.

Comment: It's likely a memory error.